# Bad dependency causes warning in sudo apt update I can't get rid of

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, updates

I am new to using Ubuntu, and know very little about using it to its full potential. I am using the 16.04 LTS version, and I recently learned about the mere existence of apt package management. I was looking into running a few windows applications on linux, and ended up trying to use PlayOnLiux. When I installed with "sudo apt install", I noticed that running "sudo apt update" worked as normal but with an added line:

```
W: http://deb.playonlinux.com/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key
74F7358425EEB6176094C884E0F72778C4676186 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

I did find a few ways to avoid getting this message in the depths of these forums, but I was hoping to understand what exactly happens to give this message, and how I can fix it (rather than just silencing it).

Any help is appreciated, and I do apologize in advance if this question was already answered somewhere that I missed. Thanks!

Edit: Thanks, I see. I don't really have the ability to fix it, because it is not on my end.

Comment: It has been asked a few times, but the problem is not on your computer: it is a problem with the repository that you are getting playonlinux from.  Until they use SHA256 or higher, this warning will appear.